# unit testing an opencv c++ program that takes a picture and saves it to file

Tags: c++, unit-testing, opencv

I'm new to unit testing and I'm wondering if somebody could tell me what a unit test for the code below might look like and do? The code uses the opencv library to take a picture and store it to file. Would you write 3 test cases to check if opening the camera, taking a picture and saving to file was successful?

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

using namespace cv;

int main(int, char**)
{
    VideoCapture cap(0); // open the default camera
    if(!cap.isOpened())  // check if we succeeded
        return -1;


        Mat frame;
        cap >> frame; // get a new frame from camera
        // do any processing
        imwrite("/home/user/cpp_test/image.png", frame);

    // the camera will be deinitialized automatically in VideoCapture destructor
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you may struggle for an answer to this question. It seems to me to lack a basic understanding of Unit Testing that would be best answered by reading. You may also find more success over on [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com)

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50105688/how-to-write-a-unit-testing-for-an-opencv-program

Answer (score 3):

The details of the implementation in C++ will depend on your unit-test framework, but basically your unit-test should be put on a dedicated class, and should be straightforward.

I will take BOOST as example:

```
BOOST_AUTO_UNIT_TEST (TestIsCameraOpen)
{
    VideoCapture cap(0); // open the default camera
    BOOST_CHECK (cap.isOpened() == true);
}
```

In this first test, you are just testing that the openCV function is able to reach the camera. If it is not able, `cap.isOpened()` will send you back "false". And your test will fail.

Then the second test should look something like:

```
BOOST_AUTO_UNIT_TEST (TestTakeAPicture)
{
    VideoCapture cap(0); // open the default camera
    Mat frame;
    cap >> frame; // get a new frame from camera
    BOOST_CHECK (frame != Mat());
}
```

In this second test, you are testing if the frame is different from the default value. If this test is failing, it means that you were not able to take a picture.

and then you have the final test to know if you are able to save a picture:

```
BOOST_AUTO_UNIT_TEST (TestSaveImage)
{
    VideoCapture cap(0); // open the default camera
    Mat frame;
    cap >> frame; // get a new frame from camera
    BOOST_CHECK (imwrite("/home/user/cpp_test/image.png", frame) == true);
}
```

On that 3rd test, we expect `cv::imwrite` to return true on sucess. If this unit-test is failing, it means that the function was not able to save the picture.

The unit-test are crucial when you are trying to debug your software. If you have an issue, for example: you run your program and you can't find any picture. You know immediately, thanks to your unit-test, what is going wrong.

If any of the unit-test is failing, you know immediately what you need to do to fix it.